# Trigger created by a script trigger is not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to run the script **"ABC2"** every day at exact **18:00**. So i've created the script trigger **"TG"** and set a trigger to run it every day between 15:00 and 16:00.

Inside my sheet, at cell **"B25"** **is the number of miliseconds left to 18:00**.

So between 15:00 and 16:00 the script **"TG"** runs and creates the trigger for script **"ABC2"**  to exact 18:00 using the milliseconds from cell **B25** just like it should do.

The problem is that the trigger created by **"TG"** for **"ABC2"** NEVER runs.

It says that **"The trigger was deactivated due to an unknown reason"**

Is it impossible to run the trigger created by another trigger?
Help me please

Here is my code:

This is **"TG"**

```
    function TG() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1_qEpIVDv1n5a8PcX6cXrAxPBzlCmTSXoikgBCVBfQC0').getSheetByName("RESUMO");
  var time = sh.getRange('B25').getValue();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('ABC2')
  .timeBased()
  .after(time)
  .create();
}
```

This is **"ABC2"**

```
function ABC2() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1_qEpIVDv1n5a8PcX6cXrAxPBzlCmTSXoikgBCVBfQC0");
  var sh1 = sh.getSheetByName('RESUMO');
  var sh2 = sh.getSheetByName('ACOMPANHAMENTO DIARIO');
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT-3', 'M/d/yyyy');
  var leo = sh2.createTextFinder(date).findAll().map(r => r.getA1Notation());
  var leo1 = sh1.getRange("B3").getValue();
  var leo2 = sh1.getRange("E3").getValue();
  var leo3 = sh1.getRange("B4").getValue();
  var leo4 = sh1.getRange("E4").getValue();
  var leo5 = sh1.getRange("C3").getValue();
  sh2.getRange(leo).offset(0, 1).setValue(leo1);
  sh2.getRange(leo).offset(0, 2).setValue(leo2);
  sh2.getRange(leo).offset(0, 3).setValue(leo3);
  sh2.getRange(leo).offset(0, 4).setValue(leo4);
  sh2.getRange(leo).offset(0, 5).setValue(leo5);
  var destinationRange = sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow() - 1, 8, 1, 3).offset(0, 0, 2);
  sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow() - 1, 8, 1, 3).autoFill(destinationRange, SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem in creating another trigger from a trigger-based function. You can try this by testing your script and provide a number in milliseconds to see if it will create a trigger successfully.

If your trigger is still not running properly, I suggest you try to use another trigger method instead of `after()` since you've mentioned that you are expecting your script to run "every day at exactly 18:00". You can try using the method below instead:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('ABC2').timeBased().atHour(18).everyDays(1)
```

Comment: Still not working. It doesn't run any trigger created by a script. I'll try to add all of the 0auth scopes and see if it's related.